# kubernetes error : skipping pod synchronization

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

i have configured kubernetes master on centos 7 and kubernetes node on another node centos 7

**services running on kube master:**

- kube-controller-manager
- kube-apiserver
- kube-scheduler
- etcd
- flanneld

**service running on kube node:**

- flanneld
- docker
- kube-proxy
- kubelet

all services are up and running and i could see the api url successfully getting all endpoints. http://kube-master:8080
however, when i am running command `kube get nodes` , getting following error :

`skipping pod synchronization. container runtime is down`

I am not getting what this error means and how to resolve this. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Seeing the same error with kubeadm 1.10.0 cluster. Work node status `NotReady`. kubelet log shows a lot of `kubelet.go:1794] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down]`

Comment: @DarVar, sometimes docker hangs on deleting a stopped container and then in turn seems to make kubelet hang and fail like this.

Answer (score 1):

`kubelet` is the only component with a dependency on the container runtime (Docker in your case). If I were you I'd start investigating the `kubelet` logs and search for references to Docker. Maybe the user configured to run kubelet doesn't have the necessary permissions to interact with the Docker socket at `/var/run/docker.sock`.

The content of your logs may help if you need further help.

Comment: where i will find the kubelet logs ?? . kubelet is run but root user so i think there are no specific permission releated issue as root is the superuser.

Comment: How do you run the `kubelet` service? If you're using systemd you can query the journal with `journalctl -u kubelet`, if running inside a container just use `docker logs <container>` or check for a `kubelet.log` file inside the /var/log directory.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem when docker got into some broken state where it was not able to remove a (specific) stopped container and was leaking zombie processes. Had to power-cycle the node in the end.

CentoOS 7 here too, still at Kubernetes 1.10.0 and Docker CE 18.03.